Why does ClickOnce publish, create multiple application version folders
Question
Why when I publish my application to a new location using ClickOnce using Visual Studio does it recreate previous versions of the tool and not only the most recent version of the tool?

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--
https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=208121.
-->
<Project>
  <PropertyGroup>
    <ApplicationRevision>318</ApplicationRevision>
    <ApplicationVersion>1.3.3.318</ApplicationVersion>
    <BootstrapperEnabled>True</BootstrapperEnabled>
    <Configuration>Release</Configuration>
    <CreateWebPageOnPublish>False</CreateWebPageOnPublish>
    <GenerateManifests>true</GenerateManifests>
    <Install>True</Install>
    <InstallFrom>Unc</InstallFrom>
    <InstallUrl>[SOME PATH]</InstallUrl>
    <IsRevisionIncremented>False</IsRevisionIncremented>
    <IsWebBootstrapper>False</IsWebBootstrapper>
    <MapFileExtensions>True</MapFileExtensions>
    <OpenBrowserOnPublish>False</OpenBrowserOnPublish>
    <Platform>Any CPU</Platform>
    <PublishDir>bin\Release\net8.0-windows\win-x64\app.publish\</PublishDir>
    <PublishUrl>[SOME PATH]</PublishUrl>
    <PublishProtocol>ClickOnce</PublishProtocol>
    <PublishReadyToRun>True</PublishReadyToRun>
    <PublishSingleFile>False</PublishSingleFile>
    <RuntimeIdentifier>win-x64</RuntimeIdentifier>
    <SelfContained>True</SelfContained>
    <SignatureAlgorithm>(none)</SignatureAlgorithm>
    <SignManifests>False</SignManifests>
    <SkipPublishVerification>false</SkipPublishVerification>
    <TargetFramework>net8.0-windows</TargetFramework>
    <UpdateEnabled>True</UpdateEnabled>
    <UpdateMode>Foreground</UpdateMode>
    <UpdateRequired>False</UpdateRequired>
    <WebPageFileName>Publish.html</WebPageFileName>
    <ProductName>Tenant Database</ProductName>
    <PublisherName>[SOME VALUE]</PublisherName>
    <SuiteName>[SOME VALUE]</SuiteName>
    <CreateDesktopShortcut>True</CreateDesktopShortcut>
  </PropertyGroup>
</Project>

To Reproduce

Open Project
Biuld > Publish Selection
Publish (which runs the pubxml pasted above)

Project Details
ClickOnce - WPF - MVVM - Desktop application
Deployed / published on an internal network server.

Users locate and run the executable on the network
It installs a local copy on the users computer @ C:\Users\[username]\AppData\Local\Apps\... with a shortcut on their desktop.
Each time the app is opened it first checks for an updated version of the software and if found updates itself.

Visual Studio Details
Microsoft Visual Studio Professional 2022
Version 17.10.2
VisualStudio.17.Release/17.10.2+35004.147
Microsoft .NET Framework
Version 4.8.09037
Installed Version: Professional
Visual C++ 2022   00476-80000-00000-AA972
Microsoft Visual C++ 2022
ASP.NET and Web Tools   17.10.341.11210
ASP.NET and Web Tools
Azure App Service Tools v3.0.0   17.10.341.11210
Azure App Service Tools v3.0.0
Azure Functions and Web Jobs Tools   17.10.341.11210
Azure Functions and Web Jobs Tools
C# Tools   4.10.0-3.24303.7+bef690dda43733707d7dccea9868fe51f34eb8a0
C# components used in the IDE. Depending on your project type and settings, a different version of the compiler may be used.
Common Azure Tools   1.10
Provides common services for use by Azure Mobile Services and Microsoft Azure Tools.
Cookiecutter   17.0.24064.1
Provides tools for finding, instantiating and customizing templates in cookiecutter format.
GitHub Copilot   0.2.889.30432
GitHub Copilot is an AI pair programmer that helps you write code faster and with less work.
Microsoft Azure Tools for Visual Studio   2.9
Support for Azure Cloud Services projects
Microsoft JVM Debugger   1.0
Provides support for connecting the Visual Studio debugger to JDWP compatible Java Virtual Machines
NuGet Package Manager   6.10.1
NuGet Package Manager in Visual Studio. For more information about NuGet, visit https://docs.nuget.org/
Office Developer Tools for Visual Studio   17.10.34627.00
Microsoft Office Developer Tools for Visual Studio
Python - Django support   17.0.24064.1
Provides templates and integration for the Django web framework.
Python - Profiling support   17.0.24064.1
Profiling support for Python projects.
Python with Pylance   17.0.24064.1
Provides IntelliSense, projects, templates, debugging, interactive windows, and other support for Python developers.
Razor (ASP.NET Core)   17.10.3.2427201+4f57d1de251e654812adde201c0265a8ca7ca31d
Provides languages services for ASP.NET Core Razor.
SQL Server Data Tools   17.10.172.0
Microsoft SQL Server Data Tools
TypeScript Tools   17.0.30327.2001
TypeScript Tools for Microsoft Visual Studio
Visual Basic Tools   4.10.0-3.24303.7+bef690dda43733707d7dccea9868fe51f34eb8a0
Visual Basic components used in the IDE. Depending on your project type and settings, a different version of the compiler may be used.
Visual F# Tools   17.10.0-beta.24228.1+dd749058c91585e9b5dae62b0f8df892429ee28f
Microsoft Visual F# Tools
Visual Studio IntelliCode   2.2
AI-assisted development for Visual Studio.

What version of Visual Studio are you using? What kind of project are you publishing? Can you provide detailed steps to help us reproduce your problem?

@MinxinYu-MSFT please let me know if you need any other specific details. I believed that the issue was only related to the pubxml file hence I didn't provide must more details.

Have you tested with a new WPF project and the latest VS2022 17.10.5? I did not encounter the problem when using the pubxml above.

@MinxinYu-MSFT Thank you for ruling it out. I'll take a look to see if I can find anything in my VS or project settings.

Waiting for your update.
